# Use ffmpeg to cut mkv file

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I tried to cut MKV video file by following command in Linux mint 16.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:39:05 -t 00:03:03 out.mkv
```

output:

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.10-6:0.8.10-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Feb  6 2014 20:53:28 with gcc 4.8.1
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[matroska,webm @ 0x1774be0] max_analyze_duration reached
[matroska,webm @ 0x1774be0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
  Duration: 00:58:35.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
    Stream #0.2(eng): Subtitle: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000
Output #0, matroska, to 'out2.mkv':
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 90k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo (default)
    Stream #0.2(eng): Subtitle: ass, 200 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
  Stream #0.2 -> #0.2
Decoder (codec id 94210) not found for input stream #0.2
```

It shows an error. I tried changing options but still can not cut the file.
Is there simplest way to cut mkv file on Linux?

Comment: @JasonC thanks for the reply. After some search I found a solution for this. Using mencoder is easier way to do this. http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2020249.html
`mencoder -ss 00:39:05 -endpos 00:03:03 -oac pcm -ovc copy input.mkv -o out.mkv` this command worked for me.

Comment: You're using a [buggy, outdated, fake "`ffmpeg`" from a fork](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017). Try downloading a recent build of `ffmpeg` from the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page (remember to execute it with the full path or with `./` as in `./ffmpeg`).

Comment: that libav looks pretty old...

Comment: @LordNeckbeard thanks for the clarification. If I download ffmpeg from that site and use it with the same command, that works well.

Comment: hopefully this link should help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131789/how-to-disable-subtitles-decoding-in-ffmpeg

Comment: hopefully this link should help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131789/how-to-disable-subtitles-decoding-in-ffmpeg

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're using a [buggy, outdated, fake "ffmpeg" from a fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017). Try downloading a recent build from the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page.

Then run your command. Note the `./` before the `ffmpeg`. This will make sure you use your new `ffmpeg` instead of the fake one in the repository.

```
./ffmpeg -ss 00:39:05 -i input.mkv -codec copy -t 00:03:03 out.mkv
```

Alternatively you could use the full path:

```
/path/to/ffmpeg -ss 00:39:05 -i input.mkv -codec copy -t 00:03:03 out.mkv
```

Using `-ss` as input option can be faster than using it as an output option: [Seeking with FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking%20with%20FFmpeg).

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I confirmed this in Linux Mint 16 Petra. Default package of ffmpeg is buggy one.

Comment: In case people don't know, this creates a 03:03 minute video starting at 39:05.

Answer (score -1):

ffmpeg -i sample.mkv -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:30 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y out.mkv -acodec copy -newaudio

Comment: thanks for this answer, however it still shows same error with your advised command.